# Show that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the dyadic intervals

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the dyadic intervals.

The collection of dyadic intervals $\triangle$ is the set $\{[j2^{-k},(j+1)2^{-k}) | j,k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Honestly, i'm a bit lost on this one. I think I can show that the borel $\sigma$-algebra contains $\triangle$, but I need some help on the other direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The set of dyadic rationals is dense in R.

Comment: How does this show that every open interval can be expressed as a countable collection of dyadic intervals and their complements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is a $\sigma$-algebra containing these intervals. Therefore it will suffice to show that any open set $O\subset \mathbb{R}$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by these intervals. Indeed, if $O\subset \mathbb{R}$ is open, and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $O_k=\bigcup\limits_{j\text{ }:\text{ }[j2^{-k}, (j+1)2^{-k})\subset O}[j2^{-k}, (j+1)2^{-k})$. You can easily check that $O=\bigcup\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}O_k$, i.e. $O$ is a set in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the dyadic intervals.

Comment: Could you help show me why it's easy to check that $O = \bigcup_k O_k$?